# Can I keep SVN synced with code from another server?

Tags: svn

There is an open source project to which I have made modifications. I don't have write access to their SVN server. I would like to version control the code in my customers SVN server (I can't change from SVN as I don't choose what software they run).

What is the simplest way to put the code into the customer's SVN repository and still be able to sync changes from the project's own repository when they happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to regularly merge the other's svn modification with your repository .

You can such something like this :

```
svn merge -r lastRevisionIMerged:head http[s]://other'svnrepository
svn commit
```

Else, just add it as external in your repository (see [link text](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html))

Last solution, use some distributed revision control like svk or git.

Comment: In an ideal world I would probably look into using SVK but until then I'll have to make do with the merge command with repository URL. I didn't know I could do that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at svk. It is able to mirror svn repositories.